# Can the Clang version of OpenCL be specified?

Tags: clang, opencl

An OpenCL program I originally wrote for an AMD GPU (RX 570) fails the runtime compilation on the Nvidia card (RTX  3060, latest drivers) with the message `<kernel>:28:5: error: use of unknown builtin '__builtin_mul_overflow'`.

Through the preprocessor macros I found the OpenCL code now gets compiled with Clang 3.4. According to the documentation, this version did not yet support `__builtin_mul_overflow()`, which was introduced in Clang 3.8.

Is it possible to specify OpenCL to use a newer Clang version?
Or are the latest Nvidia drivers indeed limited to such an old compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't control which compiler the OpenCL driver uses. You could try conditionally compiling the code to account for different compilers, but that's about it.

Comment: That's what I feared.
Thanks!